# How to add object from a class to List in another class.

Tags: c#, .net

I am not sure I am asking this question properly and have had trouble searching for what I need in this case. I have two classes. One consists of three items that I will assign.

```
namespace Common.PriceFeed
{
    public class SurchargeSKUList
    {
        public string WebSKUID { get; set; }
        public decimal AdditionalPrice { get; set; }
        public string Currency { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The other class is a list containing the items from the above class.

```
namespace Common.PriceFeed
{
    public class BaseSurcharge
    {
        public List<SurchargeSKUList> SKUList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My problem is, then I try to use BaseSurcharge, I get errors like I am using as type as a variable or that I "cannot implicitly convert type..."
My .net code is below.

Thank you.

```
if (BaseSurcharges.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in BaseSurcharges.Rows)
    {
        SurchargeSKUList newSKUList = new SurchargeSKUList();
        newSKUList.WebSKUID = row["WebSKUID"].ToString();
        newSKUList.AdditionalPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(row["AdditionalPrice"]);
        newSKUList.Currency = row["Currency"].ToString();

        BaseSurcharge newSurcharge = new BaseSurcharge();
        newSurcharge.SKUList = List<SurchargeSKUList>newSKUList;

        //BaseSurcharge List<SurchargeSKUList> newSurcharge = new BaseSurcharge
        //BaseSurcharge newSurcharge = new BaseSurcharge();
        //newSurcharge.SKUList = newSKUList;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps it's better to add `C#` to your tags. More people will see the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
newSurcharge.SKUList = List<SurchargeSKUList>newSKUList;
```

should be changed to:

```
newSurcharge.SKUList = new List<SurchargeSKUList>();
newSurcharge.SKUList.Add(newSKUList);
```

<sub>I didn't check this out on Visual Studio. So it might have some syntax errors.</sub>

But better yet - `BaseSurcharge` should have `SKUList = new List<SurchargeSKUList>();` in its constructor.

Comment: That did it thank you. As for your "better yet" Do you mean that I should drop the code into my cs file? I am a little confused about how that would work. Thank you.

Comment: @joerdie I'm not sure I'm following your question. Are you asking what a constructor is? If you're just asking what I suggested doing, then yes, If you just copy that line into `BaseSurcharge`'s constructor - it will create the `List` when an instance of `BaseSurcharge` is created (by `new BaseSurcharge()`),  and so you won't need the `newSurcharge.SKUList = new List<SurchargeSKUList>();` later. (Which will create a new List every time. Probably not what you're looking for.)